# How much memory (NOT storage capacity) is typically contained in a modern (2016) commodity SSD?

Tags: memory, ssd

Say I am writing a [Flash Translation Layer](https://flashdba.com/2014/09/17/understanding-flash-the-flash-translation-layer/) for some modern, commodity SSD. For the sake of simplicity, let's say we're working with a 128 GB SSD. How much DRAM (**NOT** general storage capacity) would I typically have at my disposal when writing this FTL? I am aware that a lot of FTL logic requires mappings to be written to stable storage, but I am curious about the amount of DRAM that some FTL firmware program has at its disposal for whatever optimizations, in-memory mappings it wants to store, etc.

Comment: @Ramhound no, I am asking how much memory the firmware has at its disposal to implement an FTL. That is (almost) completely unrelated to how much storage capacity it has. Hmmm, I'm not sure about your statement that SSDs have no memory. I am 100% sure that SSDs most certainly do have memory.

Comment: Also, there is a delay on some SSD operations. Reads typically have **very** low latency, but write and erase operations can have latencies on the order of hundreds of microseconds to milliseconds.

Comment: *"How much memory..."* -- You probably mean RAM.

Comment: @sawdust You're right, thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: *"How much DRAM..."* -- It's been a while since I took apart a HDD, but older IDE and PATA  drives used a SRAM chip for RAM, not DRAM.

Comment: @sawdust Modern SSDs (tend to) have DRAM in addition to SRAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It greatly depends. You're talking *cache*, and it can range to none (on very modern, low end drives - ), up to a 1GiB or more. As drives get bigger and faster, and ram gets cheaper *this can change*

This is roughly like asking "how long a piece of string do I need to tie a bundle".

There's no easy way to check either, short of looking it up or opening up the drive to take a peek. If you're a developer for a company that's bought a few hundred thousand drives, chances are there's an API for it, but there's no general answer for this.

Comment: Haha, I don't know about that analogy, and I also would be surprised if there wasn't some general industry-wide baseline for this. I know most storage device companies try to keep the firmware cache as small as possible because they don't make money off of it (other than for meeting I/O requirements). Also, remember that I'm asking specifically about 128 Gb SSDs in this question to avoid getting trapped in discussing generalities.

Comment: Also: some drives have **no** cache? That seems very implausible to me. Are you aware of an example of such a drive?

Comment: The one I have is an obscure model made by a manufacturer called 'King Dian'. The  *controller* is a SM2246XT. Something like http://www.tomshardware.com/news/ocz-tl100-dram-less-ssd,32764.html would be a more mainstream example. If you're talking about the paltry amount of on processor sram... that's another story, but the answer is "it depends. Look at the data sheet"

Comment: Oh I don't care about SRAM, I was curious about DRAM (that's what I put in the question). But wait, wow. Ok, I guess you're right that some SSDs have no DRAM. But what's the point of buying an SSD with no cache? Is it still more performant than an HDD even without a cache? That seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it's slower than some HDDs. So what's the point of even buying one? Also, How is it possible that its write throughput is almost as good as its read throughput? (0_0)

Comment: It makes a pretty compelling upgrade on older systems - I've had pretty impressive results swapping out the 5400rpm drives on older laptops (with windows XP) to low end SSDs and windows 10.  Its definitely a good upgrade in *many* cases, taking into account impact resistance, and quite a few other

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about I/O controller here? One of my MLC flash disk has 16 MB allocated for that if that's what you are asking. Also SSDs do have cache. They use DRAM as cache.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that I'm talking about the embedded processor that performs the FTL mapping logic rather than the I/O controller, which routes allocation requests to the FTL / SSD.